# Произвести замену по шаблону

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
<div>[21691] <a href="/catalog/pult_8p8c/" class="">Пульт 8P8C</a> <nobr>(4.00 шт)</nobr><hr size="1" width="90%"></div>
```

Добрый день как заменить  [21691] на другое значение
p.s 21691, ссылка, название, и количество может быть другими.

Comment: ну если Вы укажите `id` или `class` эллемента или родителя можно `jquery`

Comment: нет я не знаю id и class'a, нужно только на php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так

```
<?php
$text = '<div>[21691]  <a href="/catalog/pult_8p8c/" class="">Пульт 8P8C</a> <nobr>(4.00 шт)</nobr><hr size="1" width="90%"></div><div>[21692]  <a href="/catalog/pult_8p8c/" class="">Пульт 8P8C</a> <nobr>(4.00 шт)</nobr><hr size="1" width="90%"></div>';

function func_repl ($val)
{
  $array_repl = array(
    '21691' => 'new value 21691',
    '21692' => 'new value 21692',
  );

    if(isset($array_repl[$val]))
    {
        $val = $array_repl[$val];
    }

    return "<div>[$val] <a ";
}

$text = preg_replace_callback('%<div>\[([^\]]+)\]\s+<a\s+%i', create_function('$matches', 'return func_repl($matches[1]);'), $text);

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

С помощью регулярного выражение находим нужную подстроку, выделяем значение в ней и с помощью функции делает замену на основании массива соответствий.